3 phase emi filter for analog signal
I'm developing a device that needs to read analog data from a sensor located far away (~ tens of meters).
To eliminate conducted noise (150 kHz..80 MHz) I use a ferrite filter on the cable and ground through capacitors, but I would like to install ferrite filter on the board.
Are there 3 phase ferrite filters for small signals on a PCB? Or you can use several 2-phase filters by connecting them together?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Ferrite beads will not cover the lower frequeny range between 150 kHz and 10 MHz, so tiny triple common mode chokes for data lines are a better choice here.
But in this context you just want to keep the noise away from your circuit and you don't have a differential input. So three single inductors are also a good option.
Because PE often carries noise as well, I suggest to use capacitors on the circuit entry and offer a direct RF path to PE.
On the MCU side, C4 will dampen the higher frequencies and the R2/C6 low pass filter covers the lower range. C5 dampens RF back feed into your supply.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Yes, two-line chokes can be used together to filter more nets.  See example here: What is the best practice when replacing a ribbon-cable ferrite clamp with chip ferrite beads?

Mind that DC bias will not balance evenly, so it must be avoided; here, GND is decoupled to one side with a capacitor, and only low-current signals are being coupled.  Data line chokes typically saturate in the 50mA range, depending on size and value of course.
If your sensor is potentiometric and low bandwidth, as the schematic implies, I would suggest simply filtering the input low enough (under a MHz, say) that interference doesn't matter, and a CMC likely doesn't matter.  Perhaps a ferrite bead, to knock down cable resonances if applicable.
